# Is it possible to send GPS coordinates as navigation target to DJI drones through mobile SDK?

Tags: dji-sdk

I am new to the drone community. I am trying to use a drone to follow a driving vehicle and record a video, this would be part of my graduate school project.

I know DJI provides an "active track" function but it seems like the maximum speed for the tracking is around 20-25 mph, and it cannot track the vehicle at a top-down angle (drone looks straight down at the vehicle).

I have an idea to send the GPS info of the ego vehicle to my mobile device and use a customized app to read the GPS location and set it as a target so the drone can follow it.

Is it doable? Is it in general worth the effort? Or is it better off to just use the active track and work with the best angle that I can get?

Answer (score 0):

I've done that.
Send gps updates from a tracker phone to the phone connected to rc.

You have to use virtualstick mode in the MSDK. Tha max speed is 15m/s

> Virtual stick functions in the DJI Mobile SDK simulate the remote controller's joysticks, and therefore an aircraft can be automated to fly in any way a human can manually fly it. Compared to missions, this is a more complicated, but flexible way to automate flight.

Works very well.

An example:
https://youtu.be/i3axYfIOHTY?t=55
It's a little shaky, but thats fixed now :-)